# Laggy TextFields cause by useMediaQuery?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a form that only renders if the screen size is "md" or above, else I want a button that opens a modal with that form. I tried doing it with the useMediaQuery hook but the TextFields are really laggy, I'm assuming it's because of the conditional rendering so how can I do this differently ?

```
const isMobile = useMediaQuery((theme) => theme.breakpoints.down("md"));
...
{!isMobile?<MyForm/>:<Button onClick={openFormModal}/>}
```

Comment: `useMediaQuery` or conditional rendering itself should not be a problem, you probably have a large component that needs to be split into many smaller ones.

Comment: @NearHuscarl that did seem to be the problem, my small form was changing the state of the page and probably caused the whole page to re-render on each key stroke.